# Como criar um modelo com apenas alguns campos da tabela?

Tags: entity-framework, modelo-relacional

Tenho algumas tabelas com vários campos. Por exemplo, a tabela (X) tem uns 20 campos dos quais eu só utilizarei 2 ou 3.

Nessa situação eu tenho que criar os modelos com todos os campos e ignorar as propriedades no *EntityTypeConfiguration* ou existe alguma forma de eu mapear apenas os campos que minha aplicação necessita nos meus modelos?

Comment: Está usando CodeFirst ou DatabaseFirst?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira mais fácil que encontrei de resolver esse problema foi criando uma view e configurando via  Fluent Api que minha entidade se baseie nessa view e não na tabela propriamente dita.

Na configuração na tabela onde ao invés de informar a tabela deve se informar a view:

```
ToTable("VIEW_USUARIO", "Schema_Data_Base");
```

Comment: E o que mais? Como ficou essa configuração?

Comment: Na configuração ta tabela onde ao inves de infornar a tabela deve se informar a view:
`ToTable("VIEW_USUARIO", "Schema_Data_Base");`

Comment: Edite sua resposta com esta parte. Aqui nos comentários não tem formatação do código.

Answer (score 3):

Usando ORM, é sempre complicado definir mais de uma entidade para a mesma tabela.

Mas devido a esta limitação a gente acaba descobrindo que não precisa fazer isso; que fazer isso aumenta a complexidade do sistema desnecessariamente.

## Você precisa de alguns campos apenas para leitura?

Faça um select (LINQ) para um novo tipo de objeto (eventualmente anônimo mesmo) retornando apenas estes campos.

## Você precisa ler e também alterar estes poucos campos?

**Talvez aí resida um erro conceitual.**

Apenas a entidade conhece a complexidade das alterações do seu estado. Por exemplo: será que você pode mesmo alterar dois atributos de uma entidade sem que ela esteja de posse do valor de outros atributos para poder validar-se?

**Por outro lado**, você como programador é um grande conhecedor do domínio e de repente sabe que pode fazer esta alteração sem riscos, e considera importante o ganho de performance de não ter que resgatar a entidade inteira para fazer esta pequena alteração.

Neste caso, você pode fazer as alterações através de comandos UPDATE, abrindo mão de usar a definição da entidade. Isso garante a performance e deixa explícito que a alteração está sendo feita sem o conhecimento do estado completo da entidade, porque ela não foi resgatada do banco.

Usando esta opção, talvez você queira definir uma API de repositório para esta entidade em vez de manipulá-la sempre diretamente através do LINQ ou comandos diretos, de modo a centralizar em um objeto a persistência e recuperação deste tipo de entidade, o que pode melhorar a expressividade geral do código e a reutilização dos métodos customizados de persistência e recuperação.

Comment: A maneira mais fácil que encontrei de resolver esse problema foi criando uma view e configurando via Fluent Api que minha entidade se baseie nessa view e não na tabela propriamente dita.